# Loop a merge+sum function on a set of dataframes in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, merge

I have the following list of dataset :

```
dflist <- list(df1_A, df1_B, df1_C, df1_D, df1_E,
               df2_A, df2_B, df2_C, df2_D, df2_E,
               df3_A, df3_B, df3_C, df3_D, df3_E,
               df4_A, df4_B, df4_C, df4_D, df4_E)

names(dflist) <- c("df1_A", "df1_B", "df1_C", "df1_D", "df1_E",
                   "df2_A", "df2_B", "df2_C", "df2_D", "df2_E",
                   "df3_A", "df3_B", "df3_C", "df3_D", "df3_E",
                   "df4_A", "df4_B", "df4_C", "df4_D", "df4_E")
```

Each dataframe have the same structure (with the same column's names):

```
df1_A
    V1  V2
G18941  17
G20092 534
G19692  10
G19703 260
G16777 231
G20045   0
...
```

I would like to make a function that merges all the dataframes with the same number (but different letter) in my list and sums the values in column V2 when the names in V1 are the same.

In hard, I managed to do this for df1_A and df1_B with the following code:

```
newdf <- bind_rows(df1_A, df1_B) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise_all(., sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I can easily turn this into a function like this:

```
MergeAndSum <- function(df1,df2) 
newdf <- bind_rows(df1, df2) %>%
  group_by(V1) %>%
  summarise_all(., sum, na.rm = TRUE)
return(newdf)
```

But I don't really see how to call it to do the loop. I try something like :

```
for (i in 2:length(dflist)){
  df1 <- List_RawCounts_Files[i-1]
  df2 <- List_RawCounts_Files[i]
  out1 <- MergeAndSum(df1,df2)
return(out1)
}
```

I imagine something that merges+sum the df1_A to the df1_B and reassigns the result to df1_A, then calls back the function with df1_A and df1_C and reassigns the result to df1_A, then calls back the function with df1_A and df1_D, and reassigns the result to df1_A, then calls back the function with df1_A and df1_E

Then the same thing with df2 (df2_A, df2_B,... df2_E), then df3, df4 and df5.

If you know how to do this I am listening.

Comment: `bind_rows` can take a list as its argument.  It then binds all the elements of the list together.  So rewrite `MergeAndSum` to take a list as its single argument rather than a number of seperate arguments.  Then use regexes (or similar) to filter the overall list of dfs into the sublists you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bind_rows` can combine list of dataframes together. You can combine them with the `id` column so that the name of the list is added as a new column, extract the dataframe name (`df1` from `df1_A`, `df2` from `df2_A` and so on) and take the sum of `V2` column for each dataframe and `V1` column as group.

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(dflist, .id = "id") %>%
  mutate(id = stringr::str_extract(id, 'df\\d+')) %>%
  group_by(id, V1) %>%
  summarise(V2 = sum(V2, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = "drop")
```

Since you want to `sum` only one column (`V2`) you can use `summarise` instead of `summarise_all` which has been superseded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't seem to work, I get this error: Error in `bind_rows()`:
! Argument 1 must have names.

Comment: @PaulSourbé In your question you show the line `names(dflist) <- c("df1_A", "df1_B", ...`. If you run that line without error, then `dflist` should have names and `bind_rows` should work just fine on it. Make sure your real data is named, as the sample data you provided is named.

Comment: Oops, indeed a simple error of call. It's great, thanks @GregorThomas, it works well, however the "id" column added contains only "NA".